# Lectura de dispositivo javascript

Tags: javascript

Alguien seria tan amable de resolver mi duda. Me gustaría saber si es posible hacer una lectura de dispositivo con javascript como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la terminal de una app llamada termux y el código que hace visible la lectura es esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y hace el llamado de la función con un `echo -e "${model}"`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces quiero saber si se puede hacer lo mismo en javascript y que de ejemplo podía tomar?

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer esto en un navegador para obtener información del equipo del usuario? Por motivos de seguridad no se permite acceso a datos sensibles. Puedes obtener algo de información a través del objeto [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Navigator), pero no es muy confiable.

Comment: Exacto quiero algo así, es para un ejercicio de prueba